# azds up seems to take forever. Any way to debug?

Tags: azure-dev-spaces

So, I've had an Azure Dev spaces project running for a while.   Up until recently, it was working fine.   Now, It is stuck at "Syncronizing files".

Is there any way to debug what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cancelling the `azds up` command and restarting the terminal solves the problem for me whenever I am stuck anywhere. When even that doesn't work, it is a good idea to run `az login` once in a while.